# Angular Directive isn't running and templateUrl isn't showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can't find why this directive isn't runnning.
No errors of any type, link function not being called and template is not being rendered.

Original code is on TypeScript but I have reproduced exactly the same behavior in a plnkr trying to make the problem come up, but still.

Plnkr version: http://plnkr.co/edit/vBARsB9PhZ4txjlmolMM?p=preview

**JS**

```
angular.module('DirectivesApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.text = 'find this, also this';
    $scope.Items = [{
      Key: 'find this',
      Value: 'FOUND 1'
    }, {
      Key: 'also this',
      Value: 'FOUND 2'
    }];

  }]).directive('multiSelect', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'multipleSelect-template.html',
      $scope: {
        text: '@text',
        Items: '&Items'
      },
      restrict: 'A',

      link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        $scope.text = attrs.text;

      }
    };
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="DirectivesApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <multi-select text="{{text}}" Items="{{Items}}"></multi-select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Template**

```
<input type="text" disabled value="{{text}}" />
<input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in Items" value="{{item.Key}}"/><label>{{item.Value}}</label>
```

PS: trying to make a custom multiselect control.

Comment: First thing to fix is the directive config property should be `scope`, not `$scope` ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-

Comment: Also, you're using the `&` binding completely wrong. Did you perhaps mean to use `=Items`?

Comment: another problem here is your `restrict` property. you are using the directive as an element, the value should be `E`

Comment: @PrinceG that would definitely be the main problem ;)

Comment: $scope instead of scope was copy error, thanks, just fixed. working now on binding and restrict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise all the comments above, this should be all you need

```
return {
    templateUrl: 'multipleSelect-template.html',
    scope: {
        text: '@',
        Items: '='
    }
};
```

The default `restrict` is "EA" anyway and you don't need to bind `attrs.text` to the `$scope` as it's already bound in the isolate scope.